# Create a list with source from another list with some columns

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation

I have a list A and creating list B. When need list A is the datasource for the same columns in list B. When a new item creates in list A automatically need to create a item in list B with some of the columns of list A.

is possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Event-receivers` for this. To be more precise you can write `Item Added` event receiver on List A. This will copy the required fields from the current row in list A and create a new row in List B with the copied columns.

You can find sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825963/sharepoint-2010-event-receiver-item-adding-and-updating-in-another-list). You may need to modify it a bit as per your requirement.